# Undesired hover gap between lines

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a container filled with little golden squares. On `:hover`, they become black. When the mouse is over a square and goes to the next one on the left or on the right side it works fine.

**The problem is**: When the cursor is over a square and goes to another square **on another row**, there's a gap on the `:hover` effect: an area where none of them gets the `:hover` properties.

**How to avoid this flashing on hover when the mouse moves vertically across the container rows and why does it happens**?

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/freestock/pen/PNmPOY?editors=1100)

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#container span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: gold;
  vertical-align: top;  
}

#container span:hover {
  background: black;  
}

#container span:hover ~ span {
  background: tomato;  
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit in the line-height on the container. Remove it and instead set the font-size to zero:

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  font-size:0;
}
#container span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: gold;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#container span:hover {
  background: black;
}
#container span:hover ~ span {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: **1**- Thanks for the answer. **2**- I got an issue on the complete version (not the minimal example). As you see on this [**codepen link**](http://codepen.io/freestock/pen/jqmWoe?editors=1100) it's supposed to be a text on the middle of this button, but it isnt showing up I guess thats because of the parent's `font-size:0`. How can I set a different font-size for an inner element?

Comment: You can set the font size on that last div, but it also has no height.

Comment: I did open [**a question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169765/strange-behavior-on-div-child-with-font-size-0) with this issue;

Comment: the solution found is to use `px` instead of `em` since `em` font-size is related to its parent's font-size (e.g. two times zero is equal to zero).

Answer (score 5):

Could you possibly switch from `display:inline-block;` to `display:block; float:left;`?

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#container span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: gold;
  vertical-align: top;  
}

#container span:hover {
  background: black;  
}

#container span:hover ~ span {
  background: tomato;  
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The other answer was checked as the 'right one' because it fixes the OP issue with a smaller change on the **current minimal example**. However, on the complete scenario (where I also have text inside the div, not shared on OP) your's works better. So **thank you very much** for your post;